# Git: File deleted locally but changed remotely. How do I see their changes?

Tags: c#, git, merge, diff, git-extensions

On a reasonably large project I occasionally find myself in the following situation during a merge (I'm using the Windows GUI for Git called GitExtensions, but I'm equally comfortable with the command line):

> File  does not have a local revision. The file has been deleted locally (ours) but modified remotely (theirs).

I then get options to either: *"Delete file (ours)"*, *"Keep modified (theirs)"*, or *"Keep base file"*.

I understand what has happened here and what these options are, but in most cases I don't know how to proceed unless I can see the changes that were made to the file on the branch that I'm merging in. If it was an unimportant change (whitespace / formatting / 'using' statements) then it doesn't matter and I can just keep the deletion, but if they made some more significant changes then I'm going to have to spend some time manually hunting these down and merging them.

Does anyone know of a git command I can run that will show me a diff of base -> remote in this situation? At the moment when this happens I'm going over to my colleague's desk to ask them what changes they made to that file so I can continue with my merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not the best solution, but it's possibly the easiest. If you start the merge in Git  (but before you act on it) Git will create a .BASE, .LOCAL and .REMOTE file in the same location as the file you need to merge.

In the case I've outlined above either .LOCAL or .REMOTE will be missing (depending on who deleted the file), but you can still go to the folder in question and manually diff either .BASE -> .REMOTE or .BASE -> .LOCAL.

This is probably easiest for Windows users.

If you really want to use the command line you can run

```
git merge-base <mergingBranch> HEAD
```

to find out the base commit hash. Then, using part of bundacia's answer above:

```
git difftool <mergeBase>..MERGE_HEAD -- foo.file
```

Comment: Simplifying this slightly, `git diff ...MERGE_HEAD -- foo.file` should usually work.

Answer (score 1):

You can git a list of the changes made to the file on the remote with this command:

```
git log -p MERGE_HEAD -- foo
```

**Explanation:**

`foo` is the file in question.

`MERGE_HEAD` points to the HEAD of the remote branch you're merging with

`-p` causes log to print the diffs with each commit

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty close! I'm trying to get something working with the current difftool, but I need a reference to the merge base commit in order to do it. So far I have: git difftool MERGE_BASE..MERGE_HEAD $file, but it seems there's no such thing as MERGE_BASE... Is there a list of these "shortcuts" anywhere?

Comment: they're just files in the .git directory (though I'm not sure if it has a different name in windows). Here's what i'm seeing:                                                                                       

COMMIT_EDITMSG, 
FETCH_HEAD, 
HEAD, 
MERGE_HEAD, 
MERGE_MODE, 
MERGE_MSG, 
ORIG_HEAD

Comment: what do you mean by "merge base"? Could that just be HEAD? FETCH_HEAD and MERGE_HEAD look to be the same thing.

Comment: Merge_base being the result of git merge-base. It tells you the commit hash of the BASE revision when you do a three-way merge. I assumed that Git would need to keep a reference to it hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful using Git Gui. It came as part of msysgit and can be accessed from the Windows Explorer context menu.

At the point where `git merge` tells me to fix the conflicts and then commit, I opened Git Gui (see screenshot below).

In the upper-left corner, it shows all changes that are unstaged (because of conflicts). To the right of it, there's a diff of the file in question. It tells me that the local version has been deleted (first two lines), but also shows the remote changes (3rd-last line). I'm pretty happy with that!

[image: Git Gui]